# How to store logs generated by IIS server in a windows VM in azure to a blob storage?

Tags: azure, cloud, monitor

I have a windows VM running on my azure cloud. This VM is running IIS and i wanted to store the IIS server logs in my azure blob storage. How to do it?

Answer (score -1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/monitor-vm-azure?toc=/azure/virtual-machines/windows/toc.json&bc=/azure/virtual-machines/windows/breadcrumb/toc.json

The above links shows how to monitor internal services and collect log data.